# How to start an "Evicted" kube-proxy?

Tags: docker, kubernetes

I want to install and configure Web UI (Dashboard):kubernetes-dashboard on my main Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS (Xenial Xerus) server. I am getting an error and not able to proceed further as shown in the screenshot the kube-proxy node is "Evicted". Help me in running the kube-proxy node.

[[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/USGcH.png]

Answer (score 2):

First you need to know why the `POD` was evicted. You can do that by `kubectl describe pod <pod name>`.
From there you will get the eviction reason, which can be checked with [Eviction Signals](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/administer-cluster/out-of-resource/#eviction-signals)

If you are running on just one node, it's possible you run out of resources (space/cpu/ram).
After that you should do `kubectl describe node <node-name>` that will show what type of resource cap the node is hitting under `Conditions:` section.

If that won't helm and `POD` will still get evicted you should check logs by`kubectl logs <pod-name> -f` and see if there are anything helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Usually `kube-proxy` is started by kubelet from a static manifest on the node, e.g. in `/etc/kubernetes/manifests`.

A simple way to get kubelet to re-read those manifests and restart kube-proxy if required is to restart kubelet.  E.g. if you are using systemd:

```
systemctl restart kubelet
```